# Creating a small database of items, able to be checked out and returned from a web browser?

Tags: php, html, database, list, checkout

Sorry if this is formatted incorrectly, this is my first time posting here.

So I'm trying to have this database of items be able to be checked out and returned from a web browser.

I've written up a web page in html that would work, if not for me having no idea how to have user input save serverside.

Plus I have no idea where to host this. I'm kind of in over my head here, any tips on where to start?

Comment: You will need to use something like PHP. Unfortunately, this question is off topic for SO. I suggest reading some documentation on a site like [w3schools.](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp)

Comment: What you're asking is off-topic for a few reasons. I think that now would be a good time for you to go over the help area if you haven't already https://stackoverflow.com/help and the related links inside it. Read through that and you'll see how things work here on Stack Overflow. It will give you a good idea as to how to formulate a good question, to see what can and should not be asked, as well as what is expected from you. This was made and put into place in order to help (you) have a better and positive experience here on Stack Overflow, which is what everybody wants and aims for.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to do it all yourself, I'd check out some shared hosting services that offer a database + php.

Html itself can't interact with the server / store data like that. That's where PHP would come in to play, and then either MySQL/Postgres/etc would store the data.

You should have a read up on some basic PHP and learn how it interacts with databases, then you can have a form submit and store the data, then render it on another page.